# Custome Reporting in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting

I am trying to create a report using the history object of a custom object. I cannot do it using the standard reporting features in salesforce. So I am trying to accomplish this through some apex code in a visual force page. Can i make use of SOQL to do this?

Comment: reporting on field history for a custom object?

Comment: yes- trying to pull some history changes int he form of reports

Answer (score 0):

Sure, field history on custom objects can be queried by SOQL. Here is an example for my custom `Quote__c` object:

```
SELECT createdDate,Field,NewValue,OldValue,ParentId FROM Quote__History order by createdDate
```

Note the double `__`

Your VF page would use a corresponding VF controller to fetch the data. Presumably, the VF page would give the user inputs to use as filters (like date range or field name(s) of interest).

A great way to test this is to use Workbench to discover your SObjects, then use the SOQL Query feature to test out your queries before committing them to code